# How to use the jquery variable named selectedCountry in php

Tags: php, jquery

I need to use a jquery variable in PHP:
What should I do?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("select.country").change(function(){
    var selectedCountry = $(this).children("option:selected").val();

});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use AJAX to send the variable to your PHP script. Here is an example using [`$.post`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/), a jQuery AJAX shortcut method:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("select.country").change(function(){
        var selectedCountry = $(this).children("option:selected").val();
        $.post( "test.php", { countrySelected : selectedCountry } );
    });
});
```

In the `$.post` function I stated I would send the value of the variable `selectedCountry` with an identifier of `countrySelected`. Then in your PHP (test.php or whatever you name it) print out the entire array:

```
<?php
    print_r($_POST);
?>
```

The result should be something like this:

```
Array
(
    [countrySelected] => Africa
)
```

You could also address the variable directly but echoing the array's variable using the variable's identifier `countrySelected`:

```
<?php
    echo $_POST['countrySelected'];
?>
```

Which will yield:

> Africa